# back referencing end notes

Tags: cleveref, endnotes

I want to have some of my equations listed at an appendix, and referenced back from there. I am currently using end notes and cref, the problem being that I can't dynamically set a label for each one and reference back to it from the end-note. I try to use the \theendnote command but it evaluates too late causing all of my end-notes to refer to the same place (the last equation I defined).

I tried using \edef for immediate expansion of \theendnote but it didn't seem to work.

EDIT: silly me, was sketching on my MWE and I posted a bad snippet of it.

my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newcommand\grammarRules[1]{
{\scriptsize\begin{align}#1\label{gram:\theendnote}\end{align}}
\endnotetext{\cref{gram:\theendnote}\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
}

\begin{document}

\grammarRules{shambalulu}
\grammarRules{bambashushu}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

result:
[image: compilation result]

see how they're both linked to eq 2? and what are those zeros anyway?

Comment: Your MWE does not work for me. It reports `Runaway argument? {\endnote {\cref {gram:##2}{\scriptsize \begin \ETC`

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of `\newcommand\remindRule[1]`

Comment: @DavidCollins Even after fixing the missing `}` the MWE still has errors.

Comment: Please provide an MWE that does compile. Checking the errors in your MWE could help you in getting what you want without us having to slog through your non-working code.

Comment: @Nailo, right, that would solve one problem, but not necessarily all of the problems.  If you get the MWE compiling, then we can look at the endnote issue.

Comment: I edited the MWE, sorry for the mix up

Comment: Your new MWE now warns `Label gram:0 multiply defined` and `gram:0@cref multiply defined`.

Comment: @peter this is part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `\endnotetext` without ever calling `\endnotemark`, and so the counter `endnote` is never stepped. Hence every single time you called `\theendnote` you get as an output the number 0.

Incidentally, the superscript 0 in front of your endnotes are where the endnote number would go.

Since I have no idea what your desired output should look like, I am not going to be able to give you a definite fix, but perhaps (formatting aside) you want something more akin to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{gramrulec}
\newcommand\grammarRules[1]{
        {\scriptsize\stepcounter{gramrulec}\begin{align}#1\label{gram:\thegramrulec}\end{align}}
\addtoendnotes{\cref{gram:\thegramrulec}\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
}

\begin{document}

\grammarRules{shambalulu}
\grammarRules{bambashushu}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think of simply using a different counter ^^"